# Importar NPM en VueJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs

Estimados buenos días,

Les cuento lo que necesito hacer:
Quiero importar un paquete NPM "jsRofex" dentro del main.js e instanciar la clase del paquete y luego exportarla. 
Lo que tengo es esto:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import auth from './auth';
const jsRofex = require("jsrofex");
const Rofex = new jsRofex("reMarkets");

Vue.use(Rofex);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Luego quiero desde cualquier archivo .vue poder llamar a la constante Rofex, de esta manera, por ejemplo:

```
IniciarSesion(conex_Usuario, conex_Contrasena)
        {
            Rofex.login(this.conex_Usuario, this.conex_Contrasena, (res)=>
            {
                console.log(res.status);
                if(res.status == "OK")
                {
                    alert("OK");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("ERROR");
                }
            });
        }
```

Pero, al ejecutar la función me devuelve este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me podría indicar por qué puede estar pasando esto?

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Julian te recomiendo usar vuex store para tener la variable global, saludos!

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias! Lo voy a investigar para ver si me sirve y poder implementarlo. Gracias!